# Extracting Data From API in AppInventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I want to create an application that allows users to input stock quotes and display the stock price. I was following a tutorial that shows you how to extract data from Yahoo Finance which returns CSV files. I was wondering if I can work with other types of data as well because I want to get data from Sina Finance which returns data in XLS format. For instance, http://market.finance.sina.com.cn/downxls.php?date=2011-07-08&symbol=sh600900 returns XLS data. Also, another website displays a webpage, and I was wondering if I can extract information from that and use it in my application.  http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/Quote/jsonp?symbol=fb. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but it would be easier to receive a result in text format, e.g. JSON instead of downloading files. For a JSON example see [here](http://www.appinventorblocks.com/appinventor-tutorials-tips/appinventor-web-component-json-response)

You also can extract information from webpages: use the `web.get` block to get the complete source of a webpage, then parse for the info needed. Alternatively to reduce the amount of data received, you can use YQL together with XPATH, see an example [here](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#yql).

Comment: Instead of saying "thank you": here at stackoverflow you normally upvote an answer in case it was helpful. Also normally you mark an answer as answered in case it is, see also the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Thank you.